# Calling object name in a print statement. Am I doing it right?

Tags: python

I want to call the name of the object inside print statement. Car class has two objects car1 and car2. Right now I have passed the names of the cars as arguments i.e car1 and car2.. But is there another way of doing it too..Code works fine for my purpose. I just want to know if there is a way to call the object names directly in print statement rather than passing the names as arguments>

```
   class car:
       def __init__(carObj,nameofCar, name, color, worth):
           carObj.nameofCar = nameofCar
           carObj.name = name
           carObj.color = color
           carObj.worth = worth

       def printDetails(printFun):
           # right now object is called as printFun.nameofCar. Is it possible to 
           # call it as car1 and car2 directly. 
           print ( "We have a : " + printFun.nameofCar +  ". " + 
           printFun.name + "  it is :" +printFun.color + " and its worth is 
           :" + str(printFun.worth))

   car1 = car("Car1", "Red convertible", "red", 16000) # using car1 as 
   #argument
   car2 = car("Car2", "Toyota Yaris", "blue", 25000) # using car2 as 
   #argument
   car1.printDetails()
   car2.printDetails()
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think what you're asking for is [`__str__ ` and/or `__repr__`](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you try to access attributes of your class instances without typing `self.my_attribute` or in your case `printFunc.my_attribute`, you want to access them only by typing `my_attribute`.
The answer is simple: you can't.
In python, instance methods in a class always takes as first argument the instance which call the methods (this argument is by convention named `self`), so you have to use this argument in order to get attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.
1. Usually, your class variable names should start with a capital. It's just a convention. 
2. Instead of referring to the carobj to instantiate a new class object, use the `self` variable. There is a lot of good information online for you to read.

Finally, I'm not really understanding why you found it necessary to define an outer function instead of just using a `__str__` or `__repr__` method. If you're not familiar with them, you should be able to find plethora of information online as well.

**If you're using python3.6+ (i think,) please start using f-strings! They're great!